# Using inherited_resources for nested, polymorphic comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, polymorphism, inherited-resources

I am new to using inherited resources and want to use it for 
polymorphic nested comments.  I have several objects that will be 
commentable (articles, galleries, etc.) and comments can also be 
nested.  I'm using a combination of awesome_nested_set (parent_id, 
lft, rgt) with my Comment model having polymorphic commentable 
columns.

The controller needs to receive an AJAX request (only) for the create 
action and perform as below:

Posting to **/articles/12/comments/34** creates a comment with commentable equal to @article (12) and parent equal to @comment (34)

/articles/12/comments/34

Posting to **/gallery/12/comments/34**  creates a comment with commentable equal to 
@gallery (12) and parent equal to @comment (34)

I'm a bit stuck on where to begin.  Is this a good use case for 
inherited resources?

---

```
class CommentsController < InheritedResources::Base 
  respond_to :js, :only => :create 
  belongs_to :article, :cheat, :gallery, :video, :polymorphic => true 
do 
    belongs_to :comments 
  end 
  def create 
    create! do |format| 
       # How in here do I build a comment so that it handles 
polymorphism? 
       @comment.children.create(:commentable => @article or @cheat or 
@something_generic?) 
    end 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested comments are difficult. Rails resources don't provide in passing an id to the create action, so I don't think you can properly POST to the create action this way. You might need to add comment to the belong_to options, so you can post to **/comments/33/comments**. I don't know if InheritedResources support this. If it does, object creation should be automatic. You can reference stuff like parent_url too.

Comment: So then just pass in commentable_id and commentable_type as part of the comments hash?  I need to be able to set those and was initially planning to pull from the URL.